# How can i force angular to re-run its bindings, manually?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am trying to integrate angular into an older existing web-app. I have a few places where large portions of the page are re-rendered from rails partials via ajax requests.

Once a portion of the page is re-rendered in this way, any existing angular bindings (e.g.: ng-click) are lost and buttons no longer work. Is there any way to manually tell angular to re-check for binding attributes?

Answer (score 2):

If you are loading some HTML and need angular to process it you'll need to run $compile on the HTML code for angular to parse for directives and you'll need to attach a scope to the returned link function.  Show some code.  If you are simply getting new data you can use $http which will automatically call $digest for you or else you can call $digest from some other callback to notify angular it needs to update the display.

Comment: I think this could work. However in my case rails is rendering full partials and returning them via AJAX calls. Is there a way to intercept the html getting returned and compile it with Angular?

Comment: Architecturally speaking you should have a directive that wraps up the code that does the request for the HTML and then use your directive within the HTML wherever you want it to insert the data that comes back from the server side.  If you write this into a directive you can re-use that directive to load data from various sources.... come to think of it you might be able to do something with ng-include to make this work.  If you use ng-include it will fetch some HTML and compile it but there may be some problems with controlling the scope.